# Logging multiple modules/functions with different formats in the simplest way

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've 4 functions:
`main.py`
 Handlers
      `func1.py`
      `func2.py`
      `func3.py`
I want to log every function exceptions with some unique formatting; for example I've the below `logging` in **main.py**

```py
import logging
from Handlers.func1 import firstfunc

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING, filename='./main.log', filemode='a+', encoding='utf-8',
format=f"{''*50}\n %(asctime)s  ⚠ #%(levelname)s   %(message)s",
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def main(param):
    try:
        mainvar = firstfunc(param)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
    ...
```

I want to have another logging as simple as the above 3-line code like below for each of those functions (**func1.py**), that saves to the same file (I know that it maybe impossible but I don't know why!)

```py
import logging
from Handlers.func2 import secondfunc

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='./main.log', filemode='a+', encoding='utf-8',
format=f"{''*50}\n⚠ #%(levelname)s  %(message)s")

def firstfunc(fpar):
    try:
        firstvar = secondfunc(sfunc)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
    ...
```

is this possible to do so as simple as calling `logging.basicConfig`?
if not, how can I write the `logger` to do the same?
Final output should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating from `basicConfig` is not as simple as
 `loggerFunc1 = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)...`
However it's possible to log by defining `fh` as `FileHandler` and passing it as a list's element to the `handlers` function like the following:

#### func1.py

```py
# Should be added to each file (include main.py).
import logging
from pathlib import Path

# Gets the Absolute path of the main.log
LogFileAPath = Path('./main.log').resolve()
fh = logging.FileHandler(LogFileAPath, encoding='utf-8')
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format=f"\n{''*50}\n%(asctime)s  ⚠ #%(levelname)s   %(message)s",
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    handlers=[fh]
    )
# use __name__ to automatically detect the module name, or any optional string.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Stop getting duplicate logs from both functions
logger.propagate = False
#

def firstfunc(fpar):
    try:
        firstvar = secondfunc(sfunc)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    ...
```

Or you should add logger in each file using only one `basicConfig` in **main.py**...

#### main.py

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.WARNING,
    filename='./main.log',
    filemode='a+',
    encoding='utf-8',
    format=f"\n{''*50}\n %(asctime)s  ⚠ #%(levelname)s   %(message)s",
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

#### func1.py

```py
# Should be added to each function file.
import logging
from pathlib import Path

# Gets the Absolute path of the main.log
LogFileAPath = Path('./main.log').resolve()
fh = logging.FileHandler(LogFileAPath, encoding='utf-8')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(f"{''*50}\n⚠ #%(levelname)s  %(message)s")
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(fh)
# Prevents getting duplicate logs
logger.propagate = False
#

def firstfunc(fpar):
    try:
        firstvar = secondfunc(sfunc)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    ...
```

#### func2.py

```py
import logging
from pathlib import Path

LogFileAPath = Path('./main.log').resolve()
fh = logging.FileHandler(LogFileAPath, encoding='utf-8')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(f"{''*50}\n⚠ #%(levelname)s  %(message)s")
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.propagate = False

def secondfunc(spar):
    try:
        secondvar = thirdfunc(tfunc)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    ...
```

⋮

## ⚠

Pay attention to the file directory, if your `main.py` is outside of the `Handlers` folder, you should use `./main.log` in **FileHandler**, if you're defining the log file inside the `Handlers` folder, you should use `../main.log`, (⭐: use `Path().resolve()`). otherwise you'll have two separate log files in two different directories.